# Django REST rest_framework.testsAPIClient post method returns 400 bad request

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

My tests are failing to create a Designer object but I can manually create with Postman once the server is running. I suspect it's something with the APIClient?

I am using rest_framework_simplejwt and it is working nicely in other unittests. This particular action also fails in the django shell.

test.py:

```
class DesignerTest(APITestCase):
    """
    Tests Designer model, views and serializer functionality.
    """

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Setup the test environment.
        """
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            email='test@email.com',
            name='Test Name',
            password='passtest123'
        )
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.refresh = RefreshToken().for_user(self.user)
        self.access = self.refresh.access_token
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f"Bearer {self.access}")

    def test_designer_creation_successful(self):
        """Test that correct input successfully creates Designer object"""
        
        payload = {
            'first_name': 'Joe',
            'last_name': 'Aughberry',
            'date_of_birth': '1952-05-17',
            'date_of_death': '2003-09-18',
            'place_of_birth': 'Aukland',
            'nationality': 'New Zealander',
            'university': 'University of Aukland',
            'website': 'www.joeaughberrydesign.com',
            'added_by_user': self.user.pk
        }

        # Create the Desinger object through a POST request
        response = self.client.post(DESIGNER_LIST_URL, data=payload)
        
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

if I run `print(response)` this returns: `<Response status_code=400, "application/json">`  and no other error message.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should add a `print(response.content)`, you will see the json content containing what went wrong (if it's a DRF Serializer Error, which should be the case).

Answer (score 1):

I may be too late to respond, but what if it still helps somebody. The response status code 400 points to a validation error, which likely means that some of the required fields are missing, that is the request doesn't pass them. In fact, it almost certainly passes an empty dict (which can be checked by printing the `request.data` in the corresponding viewset method). The reason is that the data are passed without any specified indication that it is json. This can be fixed in two ways:

1.

```py
import json

...

response = self.client.post(DESIGNER_LIST_URL, data=json.dumps(payload), content_type="application/json")
```

2. 

```py
response = self.client.post(DESIGNER_LIST_URL, data=payload, format="json")
```

This is basically discussed in the DRF docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#creating-test-requests).